# Rank of Vandermonde matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a Vandermonde matrix
$$V = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^{n-1} \\
1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^{n-1} \\
& & \vdots \\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$
It is a simple exercise to prove that if the rank of the Vandermonde is $< n$, then the determinant is $0$ and not all of the $x_i$ can be distinct. But is the following more fine-grained statement true?

**Question:** If a Vandermonde matrix has rank $k$, then does the set $\{ x_1,\cdots,x_n \}$ contain exactly $k$ distinct elements?

Comment: A similar statement which can be used to answer your question is quoted in the [Wikipedia entry for Vandermonde matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Resulting_properties); so presumably this result is well-known.

Comment: @WillieWong I see! Thanks for the reference. I was not aware of this result.

Comment: See also (for a more general, noncommutative setting): [T. Y. Lam, *A general theory of Vandermonde matrices*, Expositiones Mathematicae **4** (1986), pp. 193--215](http://libgen.lc/scimag/ads.php?doi=10.0000/ExpositionesMathematicae/4/193-215).

Comment: If $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ has exactly $k$ distinct elements, then $V$ has a $k \times k$ invertible submatrix, and has only $k$ distinct lines, so the rank must be $k$.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault That is indeed true, but my question was about the converse statement: does the rank of $V$ being equal to $k$ imply that there are exactly $k$ distinct elements in $\{ x_1,\cdots,x_n \}$?

Comment: Well what I wrote says that the rank is equal to the cardinality of $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, which is what you want.

Comment: Oh, yes that is correct. My mistake.